# How to customize my titlepage?

Tags: titles, classicthesis

The standard titlepage is quite simple. I am looking for a very [complex titlepage](http://www.normalesup.org/~robert/pro/publications/academic/phd.pdf) and need help customizing my title page.
 It should match the  `classicthesis` doctoral thesis template

Below a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,twoside,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\XeTeXinputencoding iso-8859-1
\usepackage[marginparsep=8pt,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}


 \frontmatter
 \begin{document}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}

      %this is the place to set up my cover sheet.
      %*******************************************************
     % Abstract
    %*******************************************************
   %\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}
   \pdfbookmark[1]{Résumé}{Résumé}
  \begingroup
   \let\clearpage\relax
   \let\cleardoublepage\relax
   \let\cleardoublepage\relax

     \chapter{Résumé}
    Résumé de la thèse en français\dots


   \vfill


   \chapter*{Summary}
  Résumé de la thèse en anglais\dots


 \endgroup          

 \vfill



 \end{document}
```

Comment: What is `flyleaf`? Can you extend your question?

Comment: Do you mean a colophon?

Comment: If a flyleaf are the blank pages at the beggining and end this may help.
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188062/how-to-insert-blank-page-after-tittle-in-two-sided-document

Comment: I think he's referring to \vfil\break\null\vfil\break or something ? ...

Comment: A flyer? A leaflet? `flyleaf` sounds like the literal translation from German 'Flugblatt', meaning `leaflet`... ah, I just looked in a dictionary: It's some like a cover page

Comment: @domi Please add some more information what exactly you want to have. This could be anything depending on the language you type in, the bookbinder you like, the styles your prof likes... If you mean clear pages to protect the document, just get two pages out of the printer and surround your work on the old fashioned way. If, and I guess that's the case, you want to have a short title in front of the main title, we need information on pagination, duplex or simplex, content, and so on... Thanks!

Comment: And of course, the best way to put information like this, is a minimal working example, as all this is dependand of the document class.

Comment: @Johannes_B. I've edited my post with a mwe.

Comment: Please note the difference between a cover and a titlepage. A titlepage is different in case of taste and special regulatins dependant of a university or even institute or even supervisor. You can give information on `\author`, `\title` and so on to KOMA and it typesets the complete standard title when requested (`\maketitle`). If you want to have a specialized title, you can put the boxes on the page manually. The KOMA-author has an own project called [`titlepage`](http://www.komascript.de/node/1213). Now your question seems even more unclear to me, because one thing is for sure ...

Comment: and after the maintenance: A helper puts together a titlepage like you linked, and then
starts the hard part: »I'd rather have *this* differently.«; »Can
you make *that* italic instead of bold?«; Please make up your
mind and ask »I want this, and exactly this; can somebody help me
achieve it?«.

Comment: @Johannes_B : For sure, I didn't see the bold font. I don't have it for the moment. But, of course, I'll have to set up it with bold instead of italic.

Comment: A completely different approach woould be to contact the author and simply ask him politely for the code of his titlepage. The result would be *exactly* the same.

Comment: I already did that in a very polite french. But I didn't receive any answer.

Comment: I find that which is exactly what I was searching for : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207945/change-the-cover-page-in-classic-thesis

Comment: Please note what `classicthesis` is, a LaTeX package doing some decisions for you concerning page layout, nothing more, nothing less. What you are asking for is the standard LaTeX way, it has nothing to do with `classicthesis`.

Comment: If this is the same issue, we could close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: Not exactly. I was trying to add some aspects of "the standard LaTex way" to classicthesis, as this one doesn't allow the user to add an extended titlepage, if I'm not missing my guess.

Comment: I am still not sure what the real question is, but i am sitting above an answer right now. Hopefully it will help you. It might take a few hours.

Comment: I have the feeling that this answer will get pretty verbose. Please be patient.

Comment: Can we rename the title to a more generic one?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

[The titlepage is one of the first pages of a book or
thesis. This page contains only the title in a fashion similar to
the rest of the text within the book.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_page)

That is what Wikipedia tells us, now we have a perspective to
follow, the titlepage should match the appearance of the rest of
the book or thesis. Let us look at the standard scrbook titlepage.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fakechap}[1]{{\noindent\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@chapter{}#1\par}\chapterheadendvskip\noindent\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
\subject{Doctoral thesis}
\title{On ducks and their love for dissertations}
\subtitle{A fiction story telling the truth}
\author{domi}
\publishers{Published by the publisher\\ at a secret location}
%\extratitle{Stories of ducks}
\uppertitleback{\vspace{3cm}I want to thank Scrooge MacDuck for his financial Support}
\date{}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\addchap{Résumé}
Résumé de la thèse en français\dots
\blindtext
\vfill

\selectlanguage{english}
\fakechap{Summary}
Résumé de la thèse en anglais\dots
\blindtext
\vfill

\selectlanguage{french}
\end{document}}
```

> [image: standardKoma]

Command `\maketitle` places the predefined elements on the first
page. If you want, you can change the font using the usual
`\addtokomafont`-mechanism.

There are more elements available, e.g. `\publishers`,
`\titlehead` and `\extratitle`. Additional elements are only
typeset if they have been define by the user with some argument.
In other words, no space is reserved just in case.

Book classes do not provide an `abstract` environment as it is
usual for books to have a whole chapter to sum up the contents.
I defined a `\fakechap` command to have both on the same page and
look alike. To be honest, it is a bit of a hack, a chapter should
be of its own. 
Please note the difference in using `\addchap`. If you
are interested, you can find out more at
[How to use unnumbered chapters with
KOMA-script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193767/how-to-use-unnumbered-chapters-with-koma-script/193799#193799).

What happens if we are using `\extratitle` to the above MWE?
An additional pair of pages has been generated in the very
beginning. Seems to be a strange location for a title. This is a
fact of history, as books didn't have a hard cover a while back.
This extra title protected the book from dirt. It is also called
a *bastard title*.

Default option for book classes is the start of new chapters on
odd (right hand) pages. That means for us, we get a blank page
between title and the first chapter. If we set `\uppertitleback`
we can place a thanks note, or something else. You can even use
spaces if you need to customize a little bit.

But who decided where the elements set with `\title`, `\author`
and co are placed? It is the author of the class. In the case of
KOMA-script it was Markus Kohm. That brings us to our next
question:

## How can I design my own titlepage?

Relatively simple, as LaTeX is a macro language to place boxes.
It is like having a huge lego set and put pieces together until
satisfied with the solution.

As we now want to do the titlepage with our own hands, we don't
call `\maketitle` that would do the default stuff. Since we don't
use `\maketitle` we don't need to set the fields for it. No need
for `\title{this is the title}` et al.  *If you are using
`\maketitle` together with the `titlepage`-environment, you are
doing something wrong.*

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    Dixie dancing ducks

    A story of love, hate and fame
\end{titlepage}
\chapter{Summary}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

> [image: titlepagePlain]

Not very pleasing to the eye. We forgot to use the right pieces
to modify it. Some tweaks lead us to this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \vspace*{9em}{\centering\Huge\usefont{T1}{qzc}{m}{it}
Dixie dancing ducks\par}
\vspace{1em}
{\hfill\itshape A story of love, hate and fame}
\clearpage
    \vspace*{\fill}\hfill   \parbox{.4\textwidth}{
    \raggedleft
\scriptsize Delilah was a sad duck with a dream, being a
    Dixie dancer some day. She wasn't the best looking duck
    in town but she never cared about superficial things.
    Practicing a lot she finally became a professional Dixie
    dancer. She even fell in love. Will Delilah overcome the
    infamy and hate of her \emph{new gained friends}?
}
\end{titlepage}
\chapter{Summary}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

> [image: DDD]

Looks much better, but the page number is screwed. Using a
KOMA-class can save the day.

---

Now an example that might be used as a cover for a thesis. Using
the `addmargin`-environment, we can get some asynchronity for the
titlepage. Package `mwe` gives us some dummy pictures, we could use the universities logo instead.

> [image: domiTitlepageAsynchronous]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{addmargin}[4cm]{-1cm}
        \centering
        \hfill\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-1x1}\par
        \vspace{4\baselineskip}
        {\Huge 
        Peter Piper picked a peck\\ of pickled peppers\par}
        \vspace{4\baselineskip}
        by\par
        {\Large\textsc{Crazy Capybara}\par}
        \vfill
        in order to get a fancy degree at\par
        {\em The university of applied dice rolling}
    \end{addmargin}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

---

A titlepage for a scientific article is also possible. If the
journal provides no template, there is mostly no use in bothering
to implement their style, they will happily do it for you.

This will be just an example, if you are really working on a
titlepage for a journal, take the solid approach as mentioned
later on. Al this manual fixing up should not been done twice to get the same output.

```
\documentclass[twoside,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[%
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.75\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
        {\large
            Pendulum\par}
    presents\par
    {\Large The sonic recreation of \\the end of the world\par}
\end{center}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
    Ladies and gentlemen, We understand that you Have come tonight
    To bear witness to the sound Of drum And Bass.

    We regret to announce That this is not the case, As instead We
    come tonight to bring you The sonic recreation of the end of
    the world.

    Ladies and gentlemen, Prepare To \dots\par
    \rule{7em}{.4pt}\par
     Rob Swire, Gareth McGrillen, and Paul
    Harding;\par \href{mailto:someone@gmail.com}{Mail the
            authors}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
]
\section{Hold Your Colour}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

> [image: domiTitlepageArticleDocument]

A collection of different titlepages that can lead to your very own customized titlepage can be found at [Titlepage](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages). I'll also try to collect some [titlepages on github](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepages).

## How to adjust the title to match `classicthesis`?

The natural approach to use the rock solid KOMA-interface is
impossible, as the author of `classicthesis` decided to implement
things in *another* way. We would have to put the commands inside the
definition, which feels like rape to me, so no example for this. 
We are back at putting lego pieces together

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,twoside,headinclude=true,headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{marginparsep=8pt,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fakechap}[1]{{\noindent\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@chapter{}#1\par}\chapterheadendvskip\noindent\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
    \vspace*{7em}
    \begin{center}
        {\Large \spacedallcaps{is it really worth the trouble?}
    \bigbreak}
        An assessment of spent time adjusting badly
        implemented \LaTeX{} templates \\[2em]
        {\scriptsize \spacedlowsmallcaps{The author}}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\addchap{Résumé}
Résumé de la thèse en français\dots
\blindtext[13]
\vfill

\fakechap{Summary}
No, simple as that. 
\blindtext
\vfill
\end{document}}
```

> [image: titlepageClassicthesis]

The titlepage looks ok, but---having an up to date TeX
installation---we get a huge warning and looking at the next page
we are shocked. Our predefined *fakechap* doesn't match.
`classicthesis` loads package `titlesec` which is incompatible
with KOMA. `titlesec` adds features to the LaTeX standard
classes, `memoir` has its own way of customizing things, `KOMA`
as well. Some functionality is broken.

## How to make a solid titlepage?

For advanced users

If the layout of the titlepage is fixed by some rules or
guidelines of a corporate design, we need to make sure the user
doesn't change the appearance. 
We use the same concept of defining a titlepage, but hide it in a
package file (or possibly a class file). Just like the standard
classes, we define a set of macros for the user (`author`,
`title`, `degree` etc.). The user can input his or her data in
the document  with
no need to care about what is going on in the background and can
just call `\maketitle`.
A very basic and
non-advanced example:

```
 \begin{filecontents}{domititlepage.sty}
 \ProvidesPackage{domititlepage}[2014/11/03 titlepages domi style]
 %There is absolutely no warranty for this demo package
 % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-add-a-flyleaf-code/210280#210280
 \RequirePackage{etoolbox}
 \ifundef{\KOMAClassName}{
  \@ifclassloaded{memoir}{\PackageWarningNoLine{domititlepage}{Using
   memoir. Memoir has its own mechanism of
   generating stuff. Not loading
  `scrextend'. Aborting now}
  \endinput
 }{
  \typeout{You seem to be using a standard class.
   Using package `scrextend' for nice
  features}
  \RequirePackage[extendedfeature=title]{scrextend}
 }
 \typeout{non-KOMA branch}
}{
 \typeout{Using a KOMA class, no need to load package scrextend}
}
   \newcommand{\@supervisor}{}
   \newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\gdef\@supervisor{#1}}
   \newkomafont{supervisor}{\normalfont\normalsize}
   \newcommand{\@degree}{}
   \newcommand{\degree}[1]{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
   \newkomafont{degree}{\normalfont\normalsize}
   \newcommand*{\@thanksnote}{}
   \newcommand*{\thanksnote}[1]{\gdef\@thanksnote{#1}}
   \newkomafont{thanksnote}{\small\itshape}
   \newcommand{\@@thanksnote}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \usekomafont{thanksnote}\@thanksnote\par\end{minipage}\par}
 \renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
   \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}
   \setlength{\parskip}{\z@}
   \typeout{Typesetting the titlepage}
   \vspace{-1em}
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    University for theoretical and applied animal dance in Duckburg\par
   \end{minipage}\par
   \vspace{7em}
   {\LARGE\centering\usefont{T1}{qcs}{b}{n} \@title\par}
   \vspace{5em}
   {\usekomafont{author}\centering \@author\par}
   \vspace{2em}
   \ifx\@degree\@empty \else
   {\centering\usekomafont{degree}\@degree\par}
   \fi
   \next@tpage
   \ifx\@thanksnote\@empty\hbox{} \else
   {\@@thanksnote}
   \fi
   \vfill
   \begin{minipage}{10em}
    \raggedright
     \usefont{T1}{qcr}{m}{n}
     No animals were harmed
     during the production of
    this printed work\par
   \end{minipage}
  \end{titlepage}%
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{domititlepage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\author{Paulo Lee Peterson}
\title{Polka loving Platypus}
%\degree{Master of Stuff}
%\thanksnote{Thanks to Daisy for her support}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction to Polka dancing}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The above uses a little trick to save us time, it writes the
contents of the first environment (filecontents) to a new file
(called `domititlepage.sty`), which gives us a solid LaTeX-package
the user can load in the preamble.

The heading of this section said something about a solid method,
right before the example, i said it is non-advanced. What is
going on? We are defining some simple to remember commands like
`author` and `degree`. As the appearance of the titlepage is
given and therefore fixed, it doesn't matter in which order the
user types in its data, our `\maketitle` command takes care of
typesetting everything where it is supposed to be according to
the guidelines.  A few things a kept variable. There is an easy
to use interface to set the font of some elements provided by
KOMA-scripts font selection features. The user can decide whether
he wants to give a thanksnote or leave that out. The package
handles this.

Almost all code is hidden from the user, who might be
intimidated, hence the user cannot change anything without a bit
of effort. This seems to be quite solid, so why is it non
advanced?  The above is a syntax/language mix-up of `TeX`,
`LaTe2eX` and maybe a bit of LaTeX3 in the future. This is quite
bad style.

> [image: PLP]

## The Rock Solid Method

The author of KOMA-script started a project called `titlepage` a
few years back collecting different titlepages, defining
different languages and hence making the titlepages rock solid.
The zip folder can be downloaded at the [KOMA-project
website](http://www.komascript.de/titlepage).

Package `titlepage` provides a new interface for `\maketitle`
making it possible to give the relevant information in a quite
handy *key-value-syntax*. Not all styles (loaded by
`\TitlePageStyle{<style>}`) support all possible fields.

The thing is though, in order to get the titlepage of your
university available with the `titlepage` package, you need to
get in contact with the author of KOMA-script.

```
%% Copyright (c) 2011 by Markus Kohm <komascript(at)gmx.info>
\documentclass[a4paper,pagesize]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove option demo if you have the logo
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlepage}
\begin{document}
\TitlePageStyle{KIT}
\maketitle[%
  mainlogo={\textcolor{red}{%
      \includegraphics[width=40mm,height=18.5mm]{KITLogo_RGB}}},%
  % You may additionally change titlehead. Original definition of titlehead
  % is:
  titlehead={\usetitleelement{mainlogo}\hspace*{\fill}},%
  title=\textcolor{red}{Titel der Arbeit\\im Stil \texttt{KIT}},%
  subject=\textcolor{red}{Klassifizierung der Arbeit},%
  author=\textcolor{red}{Markus~Kohm},%
  faculty=\textcolor{red}{Fakultät für Informatik},%
  chair=\textcolor{red}{%
    Institute for Program Structures\\and Data Organization (IPA)},%
  advisor={\textcolor{red}{Titel Vorname Nachname}\and
    \textcolor{red}{Titel Vorname Nachname}},%
  referee={\textcolor{red}{Titel Vorname Nachname}\and
    \textcolor{red}{Titel Vorname Nachname}},%
  duration=\textcolor{red}{XX. Monat 20XX -- XX. Monat 20XX},%
  university=\textcolor{red}{\KITlongname},%
  homepage=\textcolor{red}{\KITurl}%
]
\end{document}
```

> [image: titlepageKIT]

---

## Further reading

[The Wikibook page on Title Creation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation), you can find some more examples linked there

Comment: I have no words to tell you my gratitude. I'll try your templates as soon as possible and tell you my impressions.

Comment: Please note, that none of the above examples are templates of any kind. They are just simple examples showing how to do stuff by oneself.

Comment: This is the best answer in teh worldz. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

@ Johannes_B : From your above examples, I customize my title page in the following way :

```
            \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,twoside,headinclude=true,headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}
      %\usepackage{geometry}
       %\geometry{marginparsep=8pt,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}
     \usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \frontmatter


   \begin{document}


   %    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
   %    \manualmark
   %    \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}                     


     \pagestyle{scrheadings}
     \newpage
     \begin{titlepage}

     \begin{center}
      \textsc{\Large Université...}\\[1cm]

      École doctorale 

      Équipe 

     Centre de Recherche \\[1cm]


     \begingroup \linespread{1,75} \selectfont 
     \textsc{\Large Title of the thesis}\\[0,75cm]
      \endgroup


     \begingroup \linespread{1,75} \selectfont 
      \textsc{\LARGE Thèse}\\[0,50cm]
      \endgroup

       Présentée et soutenue publiquement par\\[0,50cm]

       \begingroup \linespread{1,75} \selectfont 
       \textsc{\large My Name}\\[0,50cm]
       \endgroup



       Le (day-month-year)\\[0,50cm]


       Sous la direction de 

       \begingroup \linespread{1,75} \selectfont 
        \textsc{\large Supervisor's name}\\[1cm]
        \endgroup




         Pour l’obtention du grade de Docteur en ...\\[1cm]


         \begingroup \linespread{1,75} \selectfont 
          \textsc{\large Rapporteurs :}\\[0,50cm]
          \endgroup

           \\[0,50cm]

          \begingroup \linespread{1,75} \selectfont 
          \textsc{\large Composition du jury :}\\[0,50cm]
          \endgroup



            \end{center}



             \vfill
             \end{titlepage}
```

Comment: [Change the cover page in classic thesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/486635)

Comment: Why did i link my own comment? To give you the chance of improving your post. Please do so, or other people looking for help might take it on. Please do not help in distributing wrong code.

Comment: I've just saw the way you have built your own cover page (the link you did). But in France, the first page must be written in the way I indicated above. The difference with your cover page lies in the head titles : I use only one line to underline every title.

Comment: I am not talking about the appearance, you can do it the way you wan (or have to do). I am talking about the font-size switches you are not using correctly.

Comment: The classic thesis font size is 11 pt. But I had to modify it in order to make my work fit some academic requirements.